# How do I modify this working circuit to work with a single 0 - 5 V rail?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, frequency, waveform, sine

I want to build a sine wave generator, but I have just +5 V and 0 V. I build the schematic in LTSpice. If I try with +5 V and -5 V it works very well, but when I try with +5 V and 0 V it doesn't works and I don't know why? Can somebody help me? Also I need 2.5 V offset and 1 V peak to peak amplitude.

[image]

Comment: Let me get this clear: You removed the -5V supply and connected the old -5V to ground, leaving all the other ground connections unchanged.

Comment: Maybe because if you need a negative voltage on sine wave, you need a negative rail as well? Maybe you should simply ask, how do I modify this working circuit to work with a single 0 - 5 V rail? (instead of dramatic "amplifier problem")

Comment: Then re-formulate your question as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try with +5V and 0V it doesn't works and I don't know why?

Are you aware that, for an n-type JFET, the gate voltage must be less than the source for normal operation? And if the op amp V- is ground, and the JFET source is also at ground, how do you think the gate can be driven to less than ground?

What you need to do is use a couple of resistors and another op amp to generate 2.5 volts, called a virtual ground, and use that instead of ground.

And, by the way, this will automatically produce your desired 2.5 volt offset.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with a limited supply voltage in this type of circuit is that the JFET control voltage needs to have a wider range than the supply in order to keep the gain “just right” for minimum distortion. As a simple fix I’d consider making a negative rail using many tried and tested techniques such as an inverting boost converter or a switched capacitance chip. This then boils down to “how do I make one of those”. Google the words and select images to see the plethora of circuits that can be used to make negative 5 volts.